Visual Enabled does not work in rviz when running 'roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch'
Currently I am performing husky simulations on WSL - Ubuntu 20.04 - ROS Noetic environment.
I am referring to the manual on the webpage you linked : https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/husky/HuskyAMCL.html to practice the husky simulation.
I have confirmed that the packages that need to be installed as described in the tutorial manual are installed as follows
ros-noetic-husky-control
ros-noetic-husky-description
ros-noetic-husky-desktop
ros-noetic-husky-gazebo
ros-noetic-husky-msgs
ros-noetic-husky-navigation
ros-noetic-husky-simulator
ros-noetic-husky-viz
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch
roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch
The above two commands will launch the gazebo simulator and rviz, but the RobotModel - Visual Enabled feature will not work.
If you know how to solve this, please reply
Thank you.
enter image description here
For reference, I thought it was a CUDA rendering issue with rviz in WSL - Ubuntu - ROS - Rviz settings, so I ran another example file and it worked fine.
enter image description here
Therefore, there does not appear to be a CUDA GPU rendering issue with WSL.
It's hard to understand why husky's Rviz Visual doesn't work.
